# Bean injection not happening even after the presence of bean in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I am working on Spring project. In this project I have password encoder bean.

```
@Configuration
public class AppSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  public AppSecurityConfiguration() {
    System.out.println("\n\n " + getClass().getName() + "\n\n\n");
  }

  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder defaultPasswordEncoder() {
    System.out.println("\n\n\n bean is created!!!!! \n\n\n");
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  // other configurations

}
```

And the class where injection is required is this,

```
@Component
public class Encoders {

  private static PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

  @Autowired
  private PasswordEncoder defaultPasswordEncoder;


  public Encoders() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    System.out.println("\n\n\n   " + (defaultPasswordEncoder == null) + " \n\n\n"); // this has problem, as defaultPasswordEncoder is null.
    Encoders.bCryptPasswordEncoder = defaultPasswordEncoder;
  }
  
  // other methods

}
```

The *defaultPasswordEncoder* in the above class is null even though I have autowired this field.

The logs are showing that although the *appSecurityConfiguration* bean was made before *encoder* bean still the *defaultPasswordEncoder* bean is being created after *encoder* bean.

Here is the log,

```
2021-10-31 10:28:51.644 DEBUG 58508 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'appSecurityConfiguration'

 com.clone.postmanc.security.AppSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9529a353
.
.
.
.
2021-10-31 10:28:51.695 DEBUG 58508 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'encoders'


   true                // coming from Encoder#Encoder showing that            
                       // defaultPasswordEncoder bean is null


2021-10-31 10:28:51.697 DEBUG 58508 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'defaultPasswordEncoder'

 bean is created!!!!!  // coming from AppSecurityConfiguration#defaultPasswordEncoder
```

I have also tried depends on annotation,

```
@Component
@DependsOn("defaultPasswordEncoder")
public class Encoders {
 
// rest is same

}
```

Now in logs *defaultPasswordEncoder* bean is being created before *encoders* but still the injection is not happening and the `PasswordEncoder defaultPasswordEncoder` field is null.

Here is the log,

```
2021-10-31 10:28:51.644 DEBUG 58508 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'appSecurityConfiguration'

 com.clone.postmanc.security.AppSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9529a353
.
.
.
2021-10-31 10:51:27.323 DEBUG 59592 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'defaultPasswordEncoder'

 bean is created!!!!! 

2021-10-31 10:51:27.327 DEBUG 59592 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'encoders'

   true  // still the field is null.
```

Can someone tell what is happening? And to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Use constructor injection instead of property injection

```
 public Encoders(PasswordEncoder defaultPasswordEncoder)
```

Then the bean will be available in constructor.

Comment: Hmm I tried that it wasn't working, but somehow it is woking now. Any idea what the problem is with my approach.

Comment: @SeemaSharma your assumption that the autowired field will be available in constructor is incorrect. Property injection is done later in Spring beans.

Comment: No I am not assuming that. I autowired the field like we normally do i.e ` @Autowired private PasswordEncoder defaultPasswordEncoder` and then tried to use it inside the constructor. What is wrong with this?

Comment: @SeemaSharma there is a difference in `Method` and `constructor`. Can you set a instance variable without calling a `Constructor` first ? Not possible right. So, property injection cannot be done without invoking a `Constructor` first.